# Enum conversion to other Enum

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums

I have **many** Enum types which return from a service and which I want to map to my Enum types.
What I want is to create a mapper class which has all the conversion logic.
I did something like this:

```
public static class ErrEnumMapper
{
    private static Dictionary<FullErrorTypeError, eError> dictionary;

    static ErrEnumMapper()
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<FullErrorTypeError, eError>()
        {
            {FullErrorTypeError.APP, eError.APPLICATION},
            {FullErrorTypeError.INF, eError.INF},
            {FullErrorTypeError.NO, eError.NONE},
            {FullErrorTypeError.PAX, eError.PASSENGER},
            {FullErrorTypeError.SYS, eError.SYSTEM}
        };
    }

    public static eError GetEnum(FullErrorTypeError key)
    {
        var val = dictionary[key];
        if (val != null)
            return val;

        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

But since I have many other Enums, in this way, I will have to create many static fields (like the "dictionary" fields) and their equivalent method (Like "GetEnum")...is there a better way to do this?
Generic maybe?

Comment: If you want to map all enums 1on1, why not just use them?

Comment: We have a naming convention in our domain application dictated by our system architect

Comment: I don't think you can do it generically. You could do it with reflection, if you could determine generally which value maps to which other value. (Your GetEnum function could be generic, but I think you'd need an addtional dictionary of dictionaries to select the right dictionary given the type).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the integral values or names are the same for both sets of enums are the same, you can't transpose from one enum value to another without some sort of manual mapping.

Some suggestions:

1. Reuse the original enums if possible
2. Keep the integer values of the mapped enum the same as the original enum, so you can just cast from one to another.
3. Use a convention for the enum names so you can map from one to the other.
4. Use a custom attribute on each mapped enum value that indicates the correlating original enum value, and have `ErrEnumMapper` read that attribute. Still manual mapping, just perhaps reorganized.

Of course, in the spirit of KISS, I'd stick with #1, #2, or just deal with the manual mapping.

Comment: thats what I thought, but I dont have control over the service enums, their int/order and such.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not really getting what you mean.. but you can just explicitly cast them if they have the same underlying value:

```
enum FirstEnum {
    ONE,
    TWO,
    THREE
}

enum SecondEnum {
    FOUR,
    FIVE,
    SIX
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
    FirstEnum first = FirstEnum.ONE;

    SecondEnum second = (SecondEnum)first;

    Console.WriteLine(second); // prints FOUR
}
```

This allows you to keep your naming convention..